# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:58330/sockjs-node/775/15qeeqvw/websocket

Tags: firefox, asp.net-core-2.1

When executing my asp.net core 2.1 application, I get the following error in the console tab of firefox browser: This is showing as 400 Bad request in the Network tab.

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:58330/sockjs-node/775/15qeeqvw/websocket.
```

I believe I missing some CSP related entries to my meta tag but not sure which one. Below is my csp meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' http://localhost:58330/ 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Can anyone please assist?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: The error message cited in the question isn’t related to CSP at all.

Comment: Any solution to the original problem listed? Anyone?